# MySQL IDs ordered by multiples of 256?

Tags: mysql

So I have a bunch of records in a database that have a Date_Created column but most of the rows have zero'd data for that.

```
+-----+---------------------+--
| id  | Date_Created        | Other_Fields...
+-----+---------------------+--
| 2   | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | ...
+-----+---------------------+--
| 34  | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | ...
+-----+---------------------+--
| 56  | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | ...
+-----+---------------------+--
| ... | ...                 | ...
+-----+---------------------+--
```

Some of the rows contain non-zero data for this column but those are currently not the rows I'm concerned about.

What I am wondering about is why, when I order the data `by Date_Created asc`, the rows come back in a way I didn't expect to see. This is how the IDs were ordered.

```
256
512
1024
1280
1536
257
513
1025
1281
1537
2049
2
258
514
1026
1282
1538
3
259
515
1027
1283
1539
4
260
...
```

(Multiples of 256)+n, where Date_Created was essentially 0, for the whole thing.

This only happens when I `select * from table order by Date_Created`. If select individual columns (`select id, Date_Created...`), the ids come out in order.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ORDER BY date, mysql will exactly do that. If all Dates are "equal", then mysql does not care about the order INSIDE the elements with the same Dates. (because it has not been told, to do so!)

The result then is called "undefined". It will be most likely depending on the (multiple) threads mysql will use to fetch the result. The result also MAY BE DIFFERENT from call to call.

so, if you want to make sure to have the SAME order for the SAME call on the SAME data - always order by `id` last.

`select * from table order by Date_Created, id`

Comment: I'm not concerned with ordering the data, thats the easy part. What I'm wondering is what internal process makes the ids come out in powers of 2.

Comment: I think, this might depend on the data, also. Mysql may notice, that it requires XY different data rows. Then it advices each Thread to fetch an equal amount of results. So, either the `256,512,1024,...` Comes from the thread that finished first, or ist the first result of thread1, 2 and 3 - i cant tell :)